# Use variables in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

It's possible to access variables inside a package.json file with `$npm_package_[key]`. I need to make something like this, but had no success:

```
{
  "name": "core"
  "version": "1.0.0"
  "scripts": {
    "first": "echo $npm_package_myvariable"
    "second": "echo $npm_package_myvariable"
  }
  "myvariable": "$npm_package_name:$npm_package_version"
}
```

I need to reuse the value of the key `myvariable` in multiple scripts, but unexpectedly, the printed value is `$npm_package_name:$npm_package_version` instead of the expected `core:1.0.0`.

I'm currently using:

- nodejs version `v10.16.3`
- macOS Catalina `v10.15.3`

Answer (score 5):

I am highlighting 3 ways to do this. Each way is an increment to the prior way.

**1. First approach**

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "core"
  "version": "1.0.0"
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo $var1"
  }
}
```

`Start npm`:

```
var1=10 npm start
```

**2. Second approach**

First approach would fail if user fails to add var1 while running npm. Better approach is to use a default value

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "core"
  "version": "1.0.0"
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo ${var1:10}"
  }
}
```

Start npm:

- `var1=20 npm start` : Using passed value
- `npm start` : Uses defined default value

Let's now look at the final approach

**3. Third approach**

If you want to access variables in multipe scripts, you need `npm-run-all` dependency.

Install dependency:

```
npm i -D npm-run-all
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "core"
  "version": "1.0.0"
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all multi:*",
    "multi:first": "echo ${var1:-10}"
    "multi:second": "echo ${var1:-10}"
  }
}
```

Start npm:

```
var1=10 npm start
```

Comment: If these are OS specific, it may be worth pointing out or someone could inadvertently lose cross platform compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux

```
{
  "name": "core",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "scripts": {
     "first": "echo $npm_package_name:$npm_package_version"
      "second": "echo $npm_package_name:$npm_package_version"
    }
}
```

If you're using Windows

```
{
  "name": "core",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "scripts": {
     "first": "echo %npm_package_name%:%npm_package_version%"
      "second": "echo %npm_package_name%:%npm_package_version%"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're right, this way works and it's the one I'm using currently but, in terms of best reuse practices, it's not good enough. Let's assume the combination had to change and I needed to add another key, with this approach, I need to change on several places instead of just one place. Any other suggestions?